# Redux and remote / local data structure conversion

Tags: javascript, redux

I m working with Redux from a while, and I use to get some remote data from some APIs at a specific format (the backend DTOs).

The fact is that the datastructure I'm getting from the services isn't the one I want to use. I want to use a specific one only related to my client side (reduction coupling, called model on client side).

My question is : **where am I suppose to convert the remote data with its specific data structure, to my client side model ?**

I've been working on multiple projects and it seems that people are using different ways to do this :

- Using `redux-thunk`, inside the thunk, they map the remote objects to local ones
- Using a `LOAD_REMOTE_DATA` action that will be managed by a Redux reducer and that will only aim to dispatch a new `COMPUTE_LOCAL_DATA`.

While using these two approach, I will a bit strange, just like a smell inside the two ways. It's just like I m missing something, I m missing a conversation layer between my remote and local structures...

Comment: Why not pass the remote data as is along with the action, and from the reducer, call some function to do the modeling before returning the new state?

Comment: I have in mind the fact that redux may only deal with a specific datastructure format. This way, I don't have to manage multiple transformation in multiple reducers. Only dealing with the structure and deal with it

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a bit opinionated. I am using redux-saga to call external APIs. I would personally skip the approaches you have mentioned.

1. Thunk approach: I would keep the thunks or sagas generic (and hence avoid specific data modelings) so that the thunk/saga code can be reused.
2. LOAD_REMOTE_DATA approach: If you feel like doing this, a better approach will be to implement a custom redux middleware to do the modeling.

I recommend just passing the remote data as is along with the action and from the target reducer(s), call some modeling function to format the data before returning the new state